# Same project gets error in other system Yii2

Tags: yii2

I've made an application in Yii2 which contains dynamic forms. And in works fine(Windows 7 PC). When I'm copying the folder to other computer(Windoews XP) with the same database setting the dynamic forms are getting error. Other parts works fine except the dynamic form.

You can see I'm getting Loading sign when I click on + sign in the dynamic form.

[image]

Comment: This issue is already [here](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/pull/138) and [here](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/79)

Comment: Thanks InsaneSkull. I've solved it.